How do the two different definitions of crystal on infinitesimal coincide?
Let $X$ be a scheme. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_(mathematics) for the definition of a crystal via a site. But basically if $$X \leftarrow U \to T_1, T_2$$ are two nilpotent thickneings of $U$, with $T_1 \to T_2$. Then pullingback along $T_1 \to T_2$ is an iso.
Another definition supposedly (see lurie) is as a sheaf on the de rham stack, or a sheaf on $X$ with isomorphism data between infinitesimally closed points (See the link for a precise definition).
How are these the same? How does the site definition encode those isomorphisms between the value of the sheaf on infinitesimally close points.
It seems that we rigidified all possible $T \to X$ in advance, but then where did the data go?

The answer is that pullbacking along $X \leftarrow X^(2) \to X$  gives us an interesting isomorphism the data of the differential operators, see Lurie's file.
